# проверка изображения на существование (PHP)

Tags: php, парсер

как на PHP проверить существование изображение взятого с другого сайта. 
К примеру: [Существует](http://img.henchan.me/manganew_thumbs/p/1552573881_perfect-half-chapter-68/06.webp) , [Не существует](http://img.henchan.me/manganew_thumbs/p/1552573881_perfect-half-chapter-68/60.webp)

Comment: Сделать запрос, проверить код ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто проверить существование файла, то get_headers() сгодится, если нужно дополнительно проверить является ли файл изображением,а также получить его размеры для генерации превью, то лучше getimagesize()

```
function is_image($file) {
   $size = getimagesize($file);
   return (strtolower(substr($size['mime'], 0, 5)) == 'image' ? true : false);  
}
```

А способов много на самом деле:
file_exists();

exif_imagetype();

fopen();

get_headers();

curl

file_get_contents();
ит.д.